# Unknown Error in the Program

Tags: java

As you can see, it's a very simple program but Eclipse keeps giving me an error that `The method makeNoise() of type Dog must override or implement a supertype method` and I don't understand what's wrong.
It's really bizarre because I don't think there's any error.

```
public abstract class Animal {

    private String name;

    //Constructor:
    public Animal(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public abstract void makeNoise();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return (name + ", who is a generic Animal");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {

    //Constructor:
    public Dog(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    @Override public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Woof Woof!");
    }

    public void playCatch() {
        System.out.println("Oh Boy, I love playing fetch!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have more than one `Animal` class? Have you done a clean build?

Comment: Use fully qualified Animal i.e. with package name instead of just Animal

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong. u should clean your project
Project > clean

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the comments of Elliott Frisch ans SMA, this behavior could be explained by importing the wrong Animal class. You could test which class you actually use by Ctrl-clicking Animal in the line

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
```

and/or double check your import statements in Dog.java